# Возврат в activity после введения данных

Tags: activity, android, sqlite

Есть активность, в которой заполняются поля spinner выбором строки из базы данный sqlite.
Рядом со spinner есть кнопка добавления нового контакта (в случае его отсутствия в БД). По нажатию на кнопку, осуществляется переход на форму добавления контакта. После добавления контакта, нажимаю на кнопку сохранить, и перехожу назад в активность со spinner, но добавленный контакт отсутствует в списке. Он появляется только после повторного входа в активность.

Вопрос: Как сделать, чтобы после ввода нового контакта и переходе в активность со spinner, новый контакт появлялся в списке?

```
public void onClickSaveZas(View v) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etDateStart.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(Zaselenie.this, "Дата заезда не введена",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            saveState();
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        saveState();
        outState.putSerializable(ZaselenieDB._ID, rowId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    private void saveState() {
        String kvartira = (String) spKvart.getSelectedItem();
        String client = (String) spContact.getSelectedItem();
        String date_start = etDateStart.getText().toString();
        String time_start = etTimeStart.getText().toString();
        String date_end = etDateEnd.getText().toString();
        String time_end = etTimeEnd.getText().toString();
        String zas_bron = tvInfo.getText().toString();
        String days = tvInfo2.getText().toString();

        if (rowId == null) {
            long id = zdb.createNewZas(kvartira, client, date_start,
                    time_start, date_end, time_end, zas_bron, days);
            if (id > 0) {
                rowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            zdb.updateZas(rowId, kvartira, client, date_start, time_start,
                    date_end, time_end, zas_bron, days);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в onResume обновлять список контактов.

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой способ — запускать дочернюю `Activity` через `startActivityForResult()` и ожидать возвращения из неё в `onActivityResult()`. При этом можно возвращать (через `setResult()` в дочерней `Activity`) `RESULT_OK`, если обновление UI требуется, и `RESULT_CANCELED` в противном случае.

Но я бы сделал всё же иначе. Имхо, правильных путей решения этой задачи два:

1. Подписаться на изменение данных в курсоре посредством `Cursor.registerContentObserver()` или `Cursor.registerDataSetObserver()`, в зависимости от специфики задачи.
2. Связать курсор и `ContentResolver` следующим образом:

   ```
   Uri uri = <…>;
   cursor.setNotificationUri(getContentResolver(), uri);
   ```

А затем, действуем, как обычно:

```
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uri, true, <observerImpl>);
```

Где `<observerImpl>` — ваша реализация `ContentObserver`, в которой вы ожидаете изменения данных и, в этом случае, что-то делаете, например, обновляете UI.